# Javascript - Change picture on :hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

i am building a website with a mega menu (UberMenu Plugin) with wordpress.

Inside the Mega Menu I have 3 horizontal columns:

**I. Column: (33,3%)** vertical clickable menu elements (product-categories)

**II. Column: (33,3%)** Image of the Category (should change on hovering the menu elements in the I. Column)

**III. Column: (33,3%)** Short Description Text regarding the Category (should also change on hovering the same elements in the I. Column)

**Target first Column menu element:**

I tried to target the first menu element in the **I. Column** with the Chrome Console:

```
<li class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-post_type ubermenu-item-object-page ubermenu-item-523 ubermenu-item-auto ubermenu-item-normal ubermenu-item-level-4 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto">
 <a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-text_only" href=".../verbotsschilder/">
  <span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">Verbotsschilder</span>
   <span class="ubermenu-badge ubermenu-badge-inline">gestalten</span></a></li>
```

Also the first element in the **I. Column** has an ID `#menu-item-523`

**Target the picture in the second Column:**

Google Chrome:

```
 <li class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-custom ubermenu-item-object-custom ubermenu-item-4646 ubermenu-item-auto ubermenu-item-normal ubermenu-item-level-4 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto">
  <a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-target-with-image ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-image_above" href="#">
   <img width="100" height="100" alt="..." data-src="...Absturzgefahr.svg" class="ubermenu-image ubermenu-image-size-thumbnail ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="...Absturzgefahr.svg">
    <noscript><img   width="100" height="100" alt="...Absturzgefahr.svg" class="ubermenu-image ubermenu-image-size-thumbnail lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" /><noscript><img class="ubermenu-image ubermenu-image-size-thumbnail" src="...Absturzgefahr.svg" width="100" height="100" alt="..."  /></noscript>
     <span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">Bild</span></a></li></ul>
```

Also the picture has an ID in the Uber Menu settings: `#menu-item-4646`

**Target the third Column with text:**

Google Chrome:

```
<li class="ubermenu-item ubermenu-item-type-custom ubermenu-item-object-custom ubermenu-item-4648 ubermenu-item-auto ubermenu-item-normal ubermenu-item-level-4 ubermenu-column ubermenu-column-auto">
 <a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-text_only" href="#">
  <span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">Text</span>
 </a>
  <div class="ubermenu-content-block ubermenu-custom-content ubermenu-custom-content-padded">Text for the first menu element</div>
</li>
```

Also the Text in the third Column has a given ID from UberMenu plugin: `#menu-item-4648`

Now i want to Change the image in the second Column and also the Text in the third Column when hovering over the menu element in the first Column.

I am new to programming so every help is very appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the src of the image tag. So unless you can overlay another image over the image you currently have as i show below, it wont be possible.

You can use the `:hover` psuedo element to change the background CSS.
Try something like:

```
#menu-item-4646:hover {
  background: url("images/your-new-background.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

Ref: [https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-change-image-on-hover-with-css.php#:~:text=You%20can%20simply%20use%20the,change%20the%20image%20on%20mouseover](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-change-image-on-hover-with-css.php#:%7E:text=You%20can%20simply%20use%20the,change%20the%20image%20on%20mouseover).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont want to change the image (or background) when i hover over the image. Basically its: Hover over `#menu-item-523` to change `#menu-item-4646` & `#menu-item-4648` at the same time.

Comment: Gotcha, unless you can change the code of the ubermenu. I think this can only be done with javascript.